# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I am not getting an error now but my delegate is not working. I am making a custom keyboard so i have the UIViewController and a UIView. I want the UIView to call the sendKeyboardShortCut method in the UIViewController. The sendKeyboardShortCut method is not being called. Thank You

//ViewController .h

```
#import "KeyboardExtension.h"
@interface PageViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate,sendKeyboardShortCutDelegate> {
   KeyboardExtension *inputAccView;
}
-(void)sendKeyboardShortCut:(NSString*)shortCut;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITextView *tv;
@end
```

//ViewController .m

```
@implementation PageViewController
@synthesize tv;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    tv.delegate = self;
}
-(void)createInputAccessoryView{
    inputAccView = [[[KeyboardExtension alloc] init]autorelease];
    inputAccView.delegate = self;
    NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeyboardExtension" owner:self options:nil];
   inputAccView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    [self createInputAccessoryView];
    [textView setInputAccessoryView:inputAccView];
}


  -(void)sendKeyboardShortCut:(NSString*)shortCut{
    if ([shortCut isEqualToString:@"dash"] ) {

        NSRange range = tv.selectedRange;
        if((range.location+range.length)<=tv.text.length)
        {
            NSString * before = [tv.text substringToIndex:range.location];
            NSString * after = [tv.text substringFromIndex:range.location+range.length];
            tv.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",before,after];
        }


    }
}

@end
```

//keyboard view .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol sendKeyboardShortCutDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)sendKeyboardShortCut:(NSString*)shortCut;
@end
@interface KeyboardExtension : UIView
-(IBAction)dash:(id)sender;
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<sendKeyboardShortCutDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

//keyboard view .m

```
#import "KeyboardExtension.h"

@implementation KeyboardExtension
@synthesize delegate;
-(IBAction)dash:(id)sender{[delegate sendKeyboardShortCut:@"dash"];}
@end
```

Comment: Where do you call the `comma` method?  (BTW: you should use `isEqualToString:` instead of `==` to compare strings.)

Comment: there is no comma method

Comment: one method that handles all strings. even when u take that is equal part out it crashes

Comment: This: `-(IBAction)comma:(id)sender;`...where does it get called?

Comment: According to the error message, it's being called on the wrong type of object.  You define it in `KeyboardExtension` but the event target is a `PageViewController`.

Comment: what should i change? how do i change the target? sorry I'm a bit lost.

Comment: How did you implemented PageViewController?

Comment: How did you link up the touch event for the comma?  It seems as if it must have been a connection to the controller even though the action methods are defined in the view.  I'm not sure which is right for your app but it should be all one or the other.

Comment: I think you shouldn't implement IBAction in view. Try make them as IBOutlet, then add target-action to them in PageViewController.

Comment: If you have solved your original problem and you are now faced with a new one, accept the answer that helped you, and post a new question about your new problem.  Do not edit your original question into something else.

Comment: it didn't solve my problem if i doesn't work. getting rid of an error is not getting rid of the problem. there is something more.

Comment: ill except his answer once he responds and clears up one thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that:

1) your button's target is the nib's file owner and not KeyboardExtension

2) your action is setup not to send the sender, so UIKit calls -comma instead of -comma:

Also, the following code is highly suspect:

```
inputAccView = [[[KeyboardExtension alloc] init]autorelease];
inputAccView.delegate = self;
NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeyboardExtension" owner:self options:nil];
inputAccView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

A) you allocate an object that you barely use as you replace it immediately with the nib's object

B) the way to extract the object from the nib (`[nibObjects objectAtIndex:0]`) is really not robust. You should create an IBOutlet in `PageViewController` and link it in the nib

I think you should revisit the way you use nibs here.

A final (unrelated) point: why are you using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"..."]` instead of just `@"..."`?

Comment: Also, he's making `self` a delegate of the object that he's replacing and providing no delegate for the one that comes from the nib.

Comment: do you mind explaining this thing that you mentioned with the delegate more.

Comment: I think you should find a tutorial on Interface Builder and making connections between objects in the NIB and the file's owner (here `PageViewController`). They can go both ways (file owner linked as delegate of the objects or objects linked to some property of the file owner)